# Some password reset links do not work

Tags: password, link, password-recovery, change-password

There are many topics here about password reset links that don´t work but I can´t find one that is about only some links that don´t work.
Our client some times receive messages from customers saying that their reset link is not working on click and also not when pasting directly in to browser.
When I test this the link always work but this has happened several times so I still think there could be some issue but no idea where to check since it´s not issue with all links.

We use magento 1.9.3.2